# Program to flip the digits of a number and always print out answer in 3 digits

Tags: python

Write a program that reads an integer (greater than 0 and less than 1000) from the console and flip digits of the number, using the arithmetic operators / and %. The result of the flip operation should always be a three-digit number. Make sure that your program works for one, two, and three-digit inputs.

Flip Examples:
8 - 800
1 - 100
11 - 110
230 - 320 
420 - 240
45 - 540
99 - 990
etc

Code I've written below
Out of the 20 tests on stepik, only one of them fails, and I have no idea what that number is and why its failing. 
I've put in every number via a while loop and checked the values, I didn't find anything wrong with them.

Current code:

```py
user_input = int(input())
digitone = 0
digittwo = 0
digitthree = 0
final = 0
if user_input < 10:
  final = user_input * 100
  print(final)
if user_input == 10:
  final = user_input * 10
  print(final)
if 10 < user_input < 100:
  digitone = int(user_input % 10) * 100
  if digitone == 0:
    final = user_input*10
    print(final)
  else:
    user_input = int(user_input /10)
    digittwo = user_input * 10
    final = digittwo + digitone
    print(final)
if 100 <= user_input < 1000:
  digitone = int(user_input % 10) * 100
  user_input = int(user_input /10)
  digittwo = int(user_input %10)*10
  if digittwo == 0:
    final = user_input*10
    print(final)
  else:
    user_input = int(user_input / 10)
    digitthree = user_input 
    final = digitthree + digittwo + digitone
    if final < 100:
      final = final * 10
      print(final)
    else:
      print(final)
if user_input > 999:
  print(0)
```

I'm aware that this isnt the best way or the most efficient way to do it, but at the moment, I do not care

On stepik, there are 20 tests (no idea what the input numbers / tests are) and 19/20 of them pass. I have no idea what that last test is, and what the number is, and why its doing that

Comment: Try for input e.g. `203`.

Comment: Looks like flipping 100 is wrong.  It produces 100 instead of 1.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister No, result must be at least 100 to have a three-digit number.

Comment: I should say that out of 1000 cases, about 180 are wrong. :-)  You should trying wrapping up your routine to flip the digits as a function, and then loop through all 1000 cases.  Clever insight: if `i` is the original number, then `i` should be equal to `flip(flip(i))` (this is how I found all the broken cases). :-)

Comment: 100 produces 100 for me

Comment: thank you @MichaelButscher and John Szakmeister (Sorry, couldn't tag you)
it seems like 203 doesnt produce 302 and I'll try the flip thing

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister. This is not true. Flipping `1` gives `100` but flipping `100` must remain `100` because a three-digit result is required. The flipping must be adjusted to guarantee this requirement.

Comment: @MichaelButscher That is not the way I'm reading the description, and I seriously doubt your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister One given example is 230 - 320. Flipping `230` would result in `32` according to your interpretation.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Ah, I see!  That's more useful input.  Enscivwy given what MichaelButscher says (and if that is truly how it should work), then `flip(flip(i))` is not a good test.  However, you can still create a set of test cases and check them (it's easier that inputting them by hand over and over again).

Comment: Alright, i'll do that,
for now, I'm trying to figure out why cases like 203 are failing, I see no reason why they should

Comment: @Enscivwy One error looks like in the >= 100 and < 1000 case... `if digittwo == 0` looks like it should be `if digitone == 0`.

Comment: And there's also the case where `digitone` and `digittwo` are 0 that needs to be handled when >= 100 and < 1000.

Comment: I've figured it out! It kinda just stops working if one of the digits is 0 because 0*x = 0
Added if statements to fix that, and now I believe all numbers should work! (Heres the code if you would like to test that: https://hastebin.com/ebanajasiw.java)

Comment: Thank you @JohnSzakmeister and MichealButscher (Couldn't tag two users in the same comment, sorry)